# How does my application knows where to find the Dropbox API SDK v2?

Tags: api, android-studio, dropbox

I downloaded the new Dropbox SDK v2 from here:

https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-java

I unzipped it somewhere on my drive D, and I added the line:

compile 'com.dropbox.core:dropbox-core-sdk:3.0.6'

to my build.gradle file, but I don't understand, how does the project knows where on my PC to find the unzipped SDK v2 files?

Where should I configure it?

Comment: @KlingKlang Why, this is gradle, it's gonna download the SDK itself. You don't need self-configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to download the SDK. When you use this:

```
compile 'com.dropbox.core:dropbox-core-sdk:3.0.6'
```

Gradle is downloading the SDK itself (Only the first time you sync with grade). You don't need to do anything, Gradle does it for you. All you need is one line.

Comment: OK, T-h-a-n-k-s!